# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro, connecting external display

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, lenovo, hdmi, 18.04

Installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro. Everything is working fine, except the connection with an HDMI external monitor.

Once I try to connect the HDMI eternal monitor everything becomes black, only the mouse in on the screen and the Fn+up/down displays the laptop bright level.

After a while more Ubuntu return to the login screen, visible on both monitors.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just set up my Lenovo P71.  Had 2 external monitors on DVI (via docking station) with my old rig.  Now I have 1 on DVI and one on HDMI.  Please make sure you flip the monitor's input over to HDMI in order for the signal to show up.  I didn't have to tweak settings or my NVQuadro driver.